# SocketException recv failed, but why?

Tags: java, sockets, tcp

I've got a Client and a Server. The client simply sends 1 line of input to the server and then prints the response.

I'm getting a

```
SocketException (Software caused connection abort: recv failed) 
    [...]
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:168)
    at hw3.Client.readLine(Client.java:37)
    at hw3.Client.main(Client.java:28)
```

The debugger tells me that the socket is not closed at the time of the read, what else can cause this exception?

I think I'm running into issues because of the threading, does anything stick out as "doing it wrong"?

```
public class Client
{
    public static final int PORT = ReversingEchoServerDispatcher.PORT;
    private static final String host = "localhost";
    private static Socket sock;

    public static void main(String[] args)
      throws IOException
    {
        try(Socket sock = new Socket(host, PORT);
            InputStreamReader clin = new InputStreamReader(sock.getInputStream());
            OutputStream clout = sock.getOutputStream();
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in))
        {
            Client.sock = sock;

            byte[] cl = sc.nextLine().getBytes("UTF-8");
            clout.write(cl);
            System.out.println(readLine(clin));
        }
    }

    private static String readLine(InputStreamReader in)
      throws IOException
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for(int i = in.read(); i != -1; i = in.read())
        {
            char c = (char) i;
            if(c != '\n') sb.append(c);
            else break;
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
}

public class ServerDispatcher
{
    public static final int PORT = 8034;
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        try (ServerSocket serversock = new ServerSocket(PORT))
        {
            while(true)
            {
                Socket socket = serversock.accept();
                ServerLogic sv = new ServerLogic(socket);
                new Thread(() -> {
                    try {
                        sv.run();
                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace(System.err);
                    }
                }).start();
            }
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace(System.err);
        }
    }
}
```

For the record, the ServerLogic class looks something like the following. My exit code is 1, not -999, so it's not that socket.close() is failing

```
class ServerLogic
{
    Socket socket;

    public
    ServerLogic(Socket s)
    {
        this.socket = s;
    }

    public void run()
      throws IOException
    {
        try(InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream());
            OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()))
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            while(in.ready()) {
                char c = (char) in.read();
                if(c == '\n') {
                    String str = process(sb);
                    if(str != null) out.write(str);
                    else return;
                } else {
                    sb.append(in.read());
                }
            }
        } finally {
            try {
                socket.close();
            } catch(IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace(System.err);
                System.exit(-999);
            }
        }
    }

    private static String process(StringBuilder sb)
    { /* ... */ }
```

Comment: try calling `flush()` on clout on the client side after the write.

Comment: Nope, that didn't fix it.

Comment: i wouldn't use in.ready() either. there's no point. What if it returns null immediately? nothing happens... get rid of that... just read

Answer (score 0):

The server is expecting a newline `\n` to terminate the input but you never send one from the client.  `sc.nextLine()` returns the input line but does not include the terminating newline.  The `while(in.ready())` loop eventually ends and the server closes the socket without ever sending a response.

Comment: Manually appending a newline to sc.nextLine() didn't fix it (`byte[] cl = (sc.nextLine()+'\n').getBytes("UTF-8");`), did I understand your answer correctly?

Comment: I also tried changing `clout` to a `PrintWriter` and using `clout.println(sc.nextLine())`, that also didn't work.